# Should the site have a canonical post for Google search operators?

Tags: discussion

Is any of the community interested in helping to create a canonical post about Google search operators?

1. We derive a lot of traffic from Google searches and presumably users would benefit from coherent and comprehensive information about search operators.
2. It is difficult to find accurate current and/or comprehensive information
3. This would be a productive activity that benefits the entire community, both inexperienced users and experts alike.
4. I think an effort to create canonical content may allow us to provide better answers faster with references, and attract users seeking the same.

I know I've performed some tests recently, some directly related to user posts, trying to determine what works and doesn't, and it would be invaluable to have a repository of accurate information from multiple site posts, our users, and other websites.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested.

---

A few days ago, I posted an [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172397/88163) to [Where to find a list of Google search operators?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122235/88163)

On this answer, I have been collecting updated information about Google Search operators, keywords and related stuff.

It might not be the best to be considered canonical / the best way to maintain it long-term, considering that Google is continuing to evolve its signature product to keep it relevant.

Something there might help, but the most important, I think, will be to set the structure, thinking about how to keep it updated and how the updates might be handled.